# New uploaded image reverts to default image after clicking upload button in my website

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, postgresql, multer

I'm working on a website where users can upload a unique profile image for each user. However, I'm encountering an issue where the newly uploaded image reverts back to the default image after clicking the upload button.

I have an index.html file that contains the HTML structure and JavaScript code for handling the image upload. Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
                        <form id="upload-form" action="/upload-profile-image" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="YOUR_USER_ID">
                            <input type="file" id="upload" name="profile_image" accept="image/*" onchange="handleUpload(event)">
                            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                        </form>

                        <script>
                            async function getUserInfo() {
                                    const response = await fetch('/api/get-user');
                                    

                                    
                                    const user = await response.json();
                                    document.querySelector('input[name="user_id"]').value = user.id;
                                    const profileImage = document.getElementById('profile-image');
                                    console.log('Fetched user:', user); // Add this line to log the user object

                                    

                                   if (user.photo_url) {
                                    // Fetch the image data as a Blob
                                    if (user.photo_url) {
                                        const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
                                        const imageResponse = await fetch(`${user.photo_url}?${timestamp}`);
                                        const imageData = await imageResponse.blob();
                                        const imageURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(imageData);
                                        profileImage.src = imageURL;
                                    } else {
                                        profileImage.src = 'img/userdefault.png';
                                    }
                                }


                                    try {
                                    const response = await fetch('/api/get-user');
                                    if (!response.ok) {
                                        throw new Error(`Error fetching user info: ${response.statusText}`);
                                    }
                                    const user = await response.json();
                                   
                                } catch (error) {
                                    console.error(error);
                                    alert('Error fetching user information');
                                }
                            }
                                


                            getUserInfo();

                            function handleUpload(event) {
                                 event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting and reloading the page
                                const file = event.target.files[0];
                                const preview = document.getElementById('profile-image');
                                const reader = new FileReader();

                                reader.onloadend = function () {
                                    preview.src = reader.result;
                                }

                                if (file) {
                                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                                } else {
                                    preview.src = "img/userdefault.png";
                                }
                            }

                           document.getElementById('upload-form').addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
                            
                                event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from reloading the page

                                const response = await fetch('/upload-profile-image', {
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    body: new FormData(document.querySelector('form')),
                                });
                                const result = await response.json();
                                const imageUrl = result.imageUrl;

                                const user_id = document.querySelector('input[name="user_id"]').value;
                                const updateResponse = await fetch('/update-user-profile-image', {
                                   method: 'POST',
                                   headers: {
                                       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                   },
                                   body: JSON.stringify({ user_id, imageUrl }),
                               });

                               const updateResult = await updateResponse.json();

                               if (updateResult.success) {
                                   // Update the image source with the new URL
                                   const profileImage = document.getElementById('profile-image');
                                   profileImage.src = updateResult.photo_url;

                                   setTimeout(function () {
                                       window.location.href = "/index.html";
                                   }, 1000); // Redirect after 1 second
                               } else {
                                   alert('Error updating profile image');
                               }

                            });



                            
                        </script>
```

I also have a **`server.js`** file that handles the image upload and updates the user's profile image URL. It's also the home for my nodejs and postgresql databases. Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    // Get the user's ID from the form data
    const userId = req.body.user_id;
    cb(null, `user_${userId}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`);
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: fileFilter, // Add this line to include the fileFilter function
});


function fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
  const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if (mimetype && extname) {
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb('Error: Images Only!');
  }
}

app.post('/upload-profile-image', upload.single('profile_image'), (req, res) => {
  if (req.file) {
    const imageUrl = `/uploads/${req.file.filename}`;
    res.json({ message: 'Image uploaded successfully', imageUrl });
  } else {
    res.status(400).send('Please upload a valid image');
  }
});


app.get('/api/get-user', (req, res) => {
  // Replace this with the actual logic to fetch the user from the database
  // based on their email or session
  const user = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'teststudent1',
    email: 'student1@gmail.com',
  };

  res.json(user);
});

app.post('/update-user-profile-image', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { user_id, imageUrl } = req.body;
        await db('users')
            .where('id', '=', user_id)
            .update({ photo_url: imageUrl });

        const updatedUser = await db('users')
            .select('photo_url')
            .where('id', '=', user_id)
            .first();

        res.json({ success: true, photo_url: updatedUser.photo_url });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Error updating profile image' });
    }
});
```

In the above code, the **`upload-profile-image`** route handles the image upload and returns the image URL upon successful upload. The **`update-user-profile-image`** route updates the user's profile image URL in the database.

The issue I'm facing is that after clicking the upload button, the image reverts back to the default image (**`img/userdefault.png`**) instead of showing the newly uploaded image. I'm not sure what's causing this behavior.

I'm using multer to handle the images uploads.

From the table **users** that i created  for the database, it should put the new image after i upload it but problem avail.

| id | email | password | photo_url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | student1@gmail.com | 123 | /uploads/user*_*1 *_*1686727779844.jpg |
| 2 | student2@gmail.com | 1234 |  |

Here is the video of the [issue](https://streamable.com/d8dysm)

What i have tried is 1. removing the cache from the website and restarting my nodejs server, issue still appear.

2. I make sure that the image path is correct
3. debugging the function handleupload(event) code part.

```
function handleUpload(event) {
    // Remove the event.preventDefault() line
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const preview = document.getElementById('profile-image');
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function () {
        preview.src = reader.result;
    }

    if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
        preview.src = "img/userdefault.png";
    }
}
```